# Java Spring Insert Arraylist into postgresql database JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, arraylist, prepared-statement

I need to make a rest application using Spring and PostgreSQL as Database.I need to input into the database some object that contains an ArrayList of String : ArrayList < String >. My problem is that i cant find a way to set my arraylist into preparedStatement. I tried with setObject but it obviously doesn't work. It goes as follow :

```
public int insert(Location location) {
        return jdbcTemplate.update(conn -> {
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_STMT);
            ps.setInt(1, location.getParam1());
            ps.setString(2, location.getParam2());
            ps.setString(3, location.getParam3());
            ps.setString(4, location.getParam4());
            ps.setString(5, location.getParam5());
            ps.setString(6, location.getParam6());
            ps.setString(7, location.getParam7());
            ps.setObject(8, location.getArrayListDate());
            return ps;
        });
    }
private static final String INSERT_STMT =
        " insert into locations (param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, dates)"
                + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        ;
```

The table form :

```
create table locations (
    param1 int primary key
  , param2 text
  , param3 text
  , param4 text
  , param5 text
  , param6 text
  , param7 text
  , dates TEXT[]
)
```

How can i make this work? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `java.util.ArrayList` to `java.sql.Array` using `conn.createArrayOf()` and pass it as

```
pstmt.setArray("text", array)
```

Refer [this](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/using-java-arrays-to-insert-retrieve-update-postgresql-arrays/)

Comment: It woked thank you!! I just had to add : String[] data = location.getDate().toArray(new String[location.getDate().size()]); to convert my arraylist to list of String!

Comment: @WangJiaMing If it worked for you, so at least accept the answer of z21.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using preparedStatement and pass the list to the query (like "IN" clause) then you have to do this in PostgreSql, then you have -

1. Use "ANY" instead of "IN"
2. As @z21 said, convert a arrayList to sql.array

The sql syntax is:  = ANY (?) ..
Set the values in the preparedStatement for the "?"